# The system failed to determine the “mysqld” version while creating new cpanel account via WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have installed WHM on centOS7 and now I am trying to create new account but getting the database error as follows-

```
Account Creation Status: failed
Cpanel::Exception/(XID rt23j6) The system failed to determine the “mysqld” version. at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/MysqlUtils/Version.pm line 193. Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Version::current_mysql_version() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mysql/Version.pm line 27 Cpanel::Mysql::Version::get_mysql_version() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Validate/DB/User.pm line 100 Cpanel::Validate::DB::User::get_max_mysql_dbuser_length() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Validate/DB/User.pm line 157 Cpanel::Validate::DB::User::_mysql_dbuser_name_length_check("demo") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Accounts/Create.pm line 1246 Whostmgr::Accounts::Create::_validate_database_config(HASH(0x3670408)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Accounts/Create.pm line 352 eval {...} called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Accounts/Create.pm line 352 Whostmgr::Accounts::Create::_wwwacct("homedir", "", "maxpark", "unlimited", "useregns", 0, "uid", "", ...) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Accounts/Create.pm line 2971 Whostmgr::Accounts::Create::__createaccount("max_emailacct_quota", "unlimited", "maxsub", "unlimited", "dbuser", "demo", "mxcheck", "auto", ...) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Accounts/Create.pm line 3025 Whostmgr::Accounts::Create::_createaccount("max_emailacct_quota", "unlimited", "maxsub", "unlimited", "dbuser", "demo", "mxcheck", "auto", ...) called at whostmgr/bin/whostmgr5.pl line 781 main::wwwacct("wwwacct") called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Dispatch.pm line 259 Whostmgr::Dispatch::_do_call("wwwacct", HASH(0x3210150), HASH(0x3212f80)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Dispatch.pm line 157 Whostmgr::Dispatch::dispatch("wwwacct", 1, ARRAY(0x3212f38), HASH(0x3212f80)) called at whostmgr/bin/whostmgr5.pl line 257
```

This might be a very basic problem but I am a beginner at WHM-Cpanel and I am stuck here and genuinely need help if anyone can do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Whats your country ?

Maybe your country is under sanctions

There is no problem installing a WHM unless your provider has problems.

Mysql does not provide sanctions to countries but mariadb has no problem.

Clear the server and reinstall OS

Before installing WHM write this code :

```
mkdir /root/cpanel_profile
echo 'mysql-version=10.3' > /root/cpanel_profile/cpanel.config
cd /home && curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest
```

with this code you are installing mariadb instead of the mysql

Next method :

You can proxy the yum file in /etc/yum.conf

```
[main]
………………

proxy=http://<Proxy-Server-IP-Address>:<Proxy_Port>

proxy_username=<Proxy-User-Name>

proxy_password=<Proxy-Password> 

Or
proxy=http://<Proxy-User-Name>:<Proxy-Password>@<Proxy-Server-IP-Address>:<Proxy_Port>


………………
```

Next method :

Edit your /etc/resolv.conf and change your nameserver to change request

```
#nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver <your best dns server to change requests>
```